помогите связать Form1 с Form2
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static Form1 instance;
    public TextBox tb1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        instance = this;
        tb1 = textBox1;
    }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form = new Form2();
        form.Show();
    }

это код для первый и главный Form1
это уже для Form2:
public static Form instance;
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    instance = this;
}

когда нажимаю на свою кнопку из Form1 то выходит ошибка
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: "Система конфигурации не прошла инициализацию"

Изначально это исключение было создано в этом стеке вызовов: [Внешний код]

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос
